# is there an method to send multiple PHP variables to custom JavaScript function as an parameter in external file of type module?

Tags: javascript, php, html, three.js, webgl

I am working with ***three.js*** and ***WebGL***. I am currently trying to send references from the database to a custom javascript function to load a model but I am getting results ***undefined*** in the alert.
I am using a JavaScript file as a type module.

`<script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>`

here is my PHP & HTML code.

```
<div class="model-options">
   <?php
      $q_read=mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM model");  
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q_read))
      {
         echo "<div class='model1-img models'>";
         echo "<img src='".$row['model_img']."' onclick='load1model(".$row['model_link'].")'>";
         echo "</div>";
      }
   ?>
</div>
```

And here is my JavaScript code.

```
function load1model(model_value) {
   alert(model_value);
};
```

**If you want to know something else then let me know.**

Comment: When you look at the page in the developer tools, is the attribute being populated correctly?

Comment: I am not an expert can you please tell me how to check it........... thanks in advance. well i am getting an error like "Uncaught ReferenceError: load1model is not defined
    at HTMLImageElement.onclick" and when i click on it i jumped to this "onclick='load1model(ASSETS/models/car-1.gltf)'"

Comment: these errors are shown when I click on the image on the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `load1model()` isn't being quoted in the generated HTML.  Try adding escaped double quotation marks to the relevant line in the PHP, like so (note the `\"`'s).

```
echo "<img src='".$row['model_img']."' onclick='load1model(\"".$row['model_link']."\")'>";
```

After that change, the `onclick` handler should read as `onclick='load1model("ASSETS/models/car-1.gltf")'` (note the double quotes around `ASSETS...gltf`; these are needed to identify that as a string in the generated JavaScript.

Comment: Well, I just did what you said still shows undefined. I also used a single quotation \' mark but still the same.

Comment: I also used input type hidden and get this element in my function using ID and I get my desired answer but every time I click on another item it still shows the first value due to the same ID. I actually want it to perform using PHP echo statement so I don't have to add a block of code on updating my database table.